# Xampp/Lampp .jpg/.png files inaccessible while .txt is, same file permissions - Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, xampp, filesystems, lampp

I've run into an interesting issue dealing with Xampp for Linux.

Turns out, everything in my localhost site works, except .jpg and .png files - so far.

Whenever accessing a file with the mentioned extensions, I get an error 403 in return. However, when accessing a file with say, a .txt extension, then I am able to view the file its corresponding path. 
All files are placed within the same directories and have the same file permissions -rw-r--r--, yet those with .png/.jpg extensions return a 403 error - and all the anchor tags with the respective extensions cannot be displayed in the html files nor via hotlink to their absolute path in the file system.

I've tried a few different things found here in SO and other forums, but none seemed to have worked.

Things I've tried:

- I have changed the file and directory permissions to -rw-rw-rw- and even -rwxrwxrwx(I know it's bad practice, but for sake of figuring this out I tried it)
- I have even tried changing the directory and file ownerships issuing chown command to the entire htdocs folder within the lampp directory
- I tried changing the lampp configuration file to allow from all in the directory settings.
- I checked the lampp access logs and indeed all files with .png/.jpg extensions within my site all show error 403 after the GET request.

I'm not sure what else to do to get this working. I've migrated my htdocs folder from computer to computer before, all running on different distributions of Linux and have always resolved this issue by simply changing folder/file permissions through chmod, but this time it is simply not the case.

Any help and ideas would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in case anyone ever runs into this problem:

I finally solved this by deleting the .htaccess file that was within the site folder - the file contained the permissions set within the hosting provider and not the local host. For some absurd reason it never occurred to me to go through the hidden files within the directory. I did not even know about the existence of it until recently - rookie mistake but knowledge gained(Now I know the purpose of this file).

In this occasion, I migrated the site folder by downloading it from the hosting provide rather than from a different machine in which I also work locally; the hosting provider generated the file automatically.

I have now restored permissions to the corresponding and everything now works properly after removing the .htaccess file, as I don't need it locally.

Posting this here in case anyone runs into the same issue.